# Manipulating single row of pixels in OpenCV, Python. Why is it so slow?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to manipulate each row of pixels in an image.

First I've created a blank image. Then I take each row in the loaded image, shift it using warpAffine() and then concatenate the row with the blank image to fill up the image with the new manipulated rows.
I hope to get skew effect from it. My goal is to be able to change it further to get various effects.

Problem:
1: I get a blank result

2: As the script runs each cycle, the for loop gets slower and slower (in print a statement for each cycle to observe). Why is this? I'm not doing any nested loops, so in my understanding each cycle should be equally as quick. Am I filling up my RAM somehow?

If you have any other suggestion on how to manipulate each row or column individually please let me know :)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# Control Vars
background_color = (255,255,255)
shift_x = 100
shift_y = 50
color_space = cv.IMREAD_COLOR
dst = []

# Loading data
image = "Skærmbillede 2022-05-31 kl. 14.47.10.png"
img = cv.imread('Skærmbillede 2022-05-31 kl. 14.47.10.png', color_space)
rows,cols = img.shape[:2]

height,width = rows,cols

# Blank image 
base_img = np.zeros((1,width,3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Manipulators
pixel_counter = 1

for row in img:
    M = np.float32([[1,0,shift_x + pixel_counter],[0,1,shift_y]])
    slice = cv.warpAffine(img[0:pixel_counter,0:cols],M,(cols,rows))
    base_img = cv.vconcat([base_img, slice])
    pixel_counter += 1
    print(f"row{pixel_counter}done")




cv.imshow('img',base_img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The biggest issue here is that you should never call `cv.vconcat` in a loop like this since it create a new bigger array for every call resulting in a **quadratic run time**. For linear time appending, consider using lists.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I did try with lists but didn't get it to work. Have problem selecting a specific row in the image array. Right now I'm trying using np.roll instead, should give the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not just pre-allocate `base_img` to have the proper final size, and write the output of `warpAffine` into appropriately shaped views of it?

Comment: But that's kinda pointless at this point, since the whole algorithm as implemented seems mighty wonky. You claim you're manipulating single rows, but that's not the case. You never use `row`, call `warpAffine` on `img[0:pixel_counter,0:cols]` (so you're taking taller and taller slices each iteration) and you set the destination size to `(cols,rows)`, so you're really appending a full-sized image in each iteration. (so on my test with 512x512 input it produced an image 262144+1 rows tall -- no wonder it was so damn slow) You have to fix that first, then even the vconcat won't be so painful.